# SimpleStringProperty (JavaFX). Reflecting TableColumn

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I've the following declaration of `TableColumn`

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<FaAccount, String> tc_account;
```

FaAccount is as following

```
public class FaAccount {

    private Account account;
...//getters
}
```

and `Account` class in turn is map of sql table. Inside `Account` class I have `one to one` relation

```
@JsonBackReference("account_benef")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ResBenefID")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Account benefAccount;
public Account getBenefAccount() {
     return benefAccount;
    }
```

By debugging I found out that `benefAccount` is filled with necessary entries. The problem is I can't reflect its value in JavaFx table and no exceptions are thrown, just this column is empty. I do it like this:

```
tc_account.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getAccount().getBenefAccount().getNumber()));
```

How can I change above code, so that `getBenefAccount().getNumber()` is reflected in my table?

Comment: When is the benefAccount filled up? May it be after the column rendered? Do you have tc_account.setCellFactory(); set?

Comment: benefAccount is filled before setCellValueFactory. I have a Service class, where by debuging I found out that benefAccount is filled along with other values (which filled in table). I have setCellValueFactory only, it works well for other columns

Comment: Hmm maybe you have some css stylings that hide text. The other case maybe the getBenefAccount().getNumber() is null so it is being rendered as empty string.

Comment: It is not null, at least for some values, I've tried this too tc_account_contr.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getAccount().getBenefAccount() != null ?  cellData.getValue().getAccount().getBenefAccount().getNumber(): null)); And there are no any css files at all

Comment: Well then we reached the point where you should post an MCVE :). Sorry for that..